# How to update session scope-beans properly?

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-aop

I am building a servlet based web application. And I am looking for a proper way to update session-scoped beans.

I have a `UserAuthorityHolder` class which stores current user's authority. It is session scoped and instantiated when the user's session is created:

```
<bean id="userDetailsHolder" 
            class="project.access.UserAuthorityHolder" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

My question is: **Is there a good way to update one or more other session-scoped beans.**

In my situation, any update to user's authority will be effective immediately if there is a way to do so.

Comment: What's the problem? Does the `userDetailsHolder` have a reference to the user's authority?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis In the current situation, say there are two administrator active at the same time : A and B. (They both have an active session: session A and session B).
When A removes B's administrator role, B is still treated as an administrator until B restarts browser. I am looking for a elegent way to prevent it from happening.

Comment: The elegant way is to not store that in the session, but to get it from the database at each request. The database is your point of truth. As soon as you cache something in the session, you accept to use potentially stale data.